# Search for a pattern and replace something in the same line after = and ""

Tags: linux, bash, shell, powershell, ubuntu

I am trying to replace `10.10.10.10` with some other IP, which were passed as arguments during the executing of the script so it should update the code in my file contains the below code. (As example...)

```
$cat environment.ts
.....
.........
const WEB_URL = 'http://10.10.10.10';
const API_URL = 'http://20.20.20.20:8080';
.....
............
......
END OF File
```

If it is only IP address, then I can straight away use sed command as below just search for the IP : `10.10.10.10` and replace it with some IP like `1.1.1.1`

```
sed -i 's/10.10.10.10/1.1.1.1/g' environment.ts
```

But, I can't relay on IP address since the file `"filename.ts"` may have different IP's updated frequently.

So I am searching for the pattern `"WEB_URL"` and trying to replace new IP after `'='` or after `"//"` . I tried `sed` and `awk` and wasn't able to succeed

**Expected result:**

Need a command like `sed` or `awk` to replace the old IP in the above mentioned file `"environment.ts"` and it should replace the old IP with a new IP . (As mentioned above, old IP is not constant, it may be different so the `sed` or `awk` command which I use should search with the pattern like `WEB_URL` or `API_URL` and replace the new IP next to `'='` or `http//`)

**From:**

```
.....
const WEB_URL = 'http://<OLD_IP1>';
const API_URL = 'http://<OLD_IP2>:8080';
.....
```

**To:**

```
const WEB_URL = 'http://<NEW_IP1>';
const API_URL = 'http://<NEW_IP2>:8080';
```

Comment: please, post some sample data to work with - and how you want the output to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sed` form that locates an occurrence and then uses alternate delimiters to avoid having to escape `'/'` characters can be written:

```
sed '/locate/s#find#replace#'
```

But since you want to be able to pass the IP as a variable, you need to double-quote the expression so variable expansion takes place and we will want to use `{x,y}` quantifiers, so we will need the `-r` option to enable *extended regex* matching, resulting in the form:

```
sed -r "/locate/s#find#replace#"
```

In your case given the IP provided in the variable `ip` and your desire to locate either `WEB_URL` or `API_URL` (followed by a whitespace and `'='` sign) and then only replace the IP address with the one contained in `$ip`, you could use:

```
sed -r "/(WEB|API)_URL\s=/s#[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}#$ip#"
```

Where your

- *locate* is `/(WEB|API)_URL\s=/`
- *find* for the IP is `[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}`
- *replace* is `$ip`

**Example Input File**

The example file shows `OTH_URL` and `API_URL` (not followed by whitespace and an `'='`) that remain untouched:

```
$ cat environment.ts
const OTH_URL = 'http://10.10.10.10';
const WEB_URL = 'http://10.10.10.10';
const API_URL = 'http://20.20.20.20:8080';
const API_URL (can either be 'http://10.10.10.10' or 'http://10.10.10.10:8080')
```

Running the `sed` expression on your example file above would result in:

```
$ ip=12.12.12.12
$ sed -r "/(WEB|API)_URL\s=/s#[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}#$ip#" \
environment.ts
const OTH_URL = 'http://10.10.10.10';
const WEB_URL = 'http://12.12.12.12';
const API_URL = 'http://12.12.12.12:8080';
const API_URL (can either be 'http://10.10.10.10' or 'http://10.10.10.10:8080')
```

Where neither the `OTH_URL` line or the line where `API_URL` is not followed by whitespace and an `'='` remain unchanged.

You will need to make separate calls to change `WEB_URL` and `API_URL` to different IP addresses, if that is wanted. That can be done by using separate `sed` expressions `-e`, example:

```
$ ip1=12.12.12.12
$ ip2=14.14.14.14
$ sed -r -e "/WEB_URL\s=/s#[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}#$ip1#" \
         -e "/API_URL\s=/s#[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}#$ip2#" \
         environment.ts
const OTH_URL = 'http://10.10.10.10';
const WEB_URL = 'http://12.12.12.12';
const API_URL = 'http://14.14.14.14:8080';
const API_URL (can either be 'http://10.10.10.10' or 'http://10.10.10.10:8080')
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this is a lot more work than `sed`, but it does work. The filename, old string, and new string can all be made .ps1 script parameters.

```
$filetoworkon = 'environment.ts'
$old = '10.10.10.10'
$new = '7.7.7.7'

Get-Content $filetoworkon |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace [regex]::Escape($old), $new
    }
```

Comment: You need to do `$_ -replace [regex]::Escape($old), $new`, since the dots in the string have special meaning in regex, namely _any single character_ (and `-replace` uses regex)..

Comment: @Theo - Thank you for that suggestion. Change made.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# POSIX compliant shell script to replace WEB_URL and API_URL
# into environment.ts

NEW_WEB_URL='http://127.0.0.1/'
NEW_API_URL='http://127.0.0.1:8080/'

var_replace_value() {
  # Creates a sed command to replace
  # varname = "something" to varname = "somethingelse"
  # @Params
  # $1: varname
  # $2: newvalue
  [ $# -eq 2 ] || return 1

  _local_varname=''
  _local_newvalue=''

  # Escape parameters to fit a sed command
  _local_varname="$(echo "${1}" | \
    sed \
      --posix \
      --regexp-extended 's/([\\\/\(\)\{\}\[\$\^]|\])/\\\1/g')"
  _local_newvalue="$(echo "${2}" | \
    sed \
      --posix \
      --regexp-extended 's/([\\\/\(\)\{\}\[\$\^]|\])/\\\1/g')"

  env printf "s/(%s[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*['\"])[^'\"]+/\\\\1%s/g" \
    "${_local_varname}" \
    "${_local_newvalue}"
}

# Build the sed script to replace the URLs
WEB_URL_REPLACE_CMD="$(var_replace_value 'WEB_URL' "${NEW_WEB_URL}")"
API_URL_REPLACE_CMD="$(var_replace_value 'API_URL' "${NEW_API_URL}")"
URL_REPLACE_SED_CMDS="${WEB_URL_REPLACE_CMD};${API_URL_REPLACE_CMD}"

sed \
--posix \
--in-place='.bak' \
--regexp-extended "${URL_REPLACE_SED_CMDS}" environment.ts
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy done with powershell:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Collections
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Text.RegularExpressions

[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$content = @()

$inputFile   = 'D:\content.txt'
$outputFile  = 'D:\content1.txt'

$regex       = '\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b'

$newIP1      = '1.1.1.1'
$newIP2      = '1.1.1.2'

foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($inputFile)) {

    if( $line -like '*API_URL*' ) {
        [void]$content.Add( ($line -replace $regex, $newIP2) )
    elseif( $line -like '*WEB_URL*' ) {
        [void]$content.Add( ($line -replace $regex, $newIP1) )            }
    else {
        [void]$content.Add( $line )
    }
}

[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines( $outputFile, $content ) | Out-Null
```

Comment: Nice; a few tips: No need for the `Add-Type` calls - the assemblies underlying the types of interest are available by default in PowerShell sessions. The `[void]` casts and `Out-Null` calls are unnecessary, because the methods you call don't return values. It is both more and convenient and more efficient to let PowerShell collect output in an array rather than building your own list in `$content`; simply use _implicit output_ in your `foreach` loop and assign the `foreach` loop directly to a variable (`$content = foreach ...`).

Comment: Also, PowerShell offers `Get-Content` for reading a text file line by line, and `Set-Content` for writing to a text file; using the `System.IO` types directly is only called for if performance is a concern.